# How to find all combinations (subset) of any size of an array in postgresql

Tags: arrays, postgresql, combinations, plpgsql

Given an array, how to find all combinations (subsets) of elements of a certain size in postgresql. For example, given an array [1, 2, 3, 4] all combinations of size 3 would be

```
[1, 2, 3],
[1, 2, 4],
[1, 3, 4],
[2, 3, 4]
```

Order is not important in combinations and therefore [1, 2, 3] and [3, 2, 1] are considered the same combination.

**Update:**
The size of the combinations required must be specified at run-time as a parameter, so that the same function/query can be used to find combinations of any size n <= size of the array. *The existing solution works only for combinations of size 3 and needs one additional cross join for every increase in the size, which is clearly not practical.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following function produces all the combinations of the requested size as a set of rows with one combination per row:

```
create or replace function get_combinations(source anyarray, size int) returns setof anyarray as $$
 with recursive combinations(combination, indices) as (
   select source[i:i], array[i] from generate_subscripts(source, 1) i
   union all
   select c.combination || source[j], c.indices || j
   from   combinations c, generate_subscripts(source, 1) j
   where  j > all(c.indices) and
          array_length(c.combination, 1) < size
 )
 select combination from combinations
 where  array_length(combination, 1) = size;
$$ language sql;
```

This function is polymorphic in the array type.