# Count all existing combinations of groupings of records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these db tables

- questions: id, text
- answers: id, text, question_id
- answer_tags: id, answer_id, tag_id
- tags: id, text

---

- question has has many answers
- answer has many tags through answer_tags, belongs to question
- tag has many answers through answer_tags
- An answer has an unlimited number of tags

I would like to show all combinations of groupings of tags that exist ordered by count

Examples data

```
Question 1, Answer 1, tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4
Question 2, Answer 2, tag2, tag3, tag4
Question 3, Answer 3, tag3, tag4
Question 4, Answer 4, tag4
Question 5, Answer 5, tag3, tag4, tag5
Question 1, Answer 6, <no tags>
```

How can I solve this using SQL?

I'm not sure if this is possible with SQL but if it does I think it would need `RECURSIVE` method.

Expected results:

```
tag3, tag4 occur 4 times
tag2, tag3, tag4 occur 2 times
tag2, tag3 occur  2 times
```

We would only return results with groupings greater than 1. No single tag is ever returned, it must be at least 2 tags together to be counted.

Comment: In what sense is "tag2, tag3, tag4" a *pair*? Why are "tag3, tag4, tag5" and "tag3, tag5" *not* pairs in your expected results?

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated the question. The goal is to identify all groupings that occur more than once. tag2, tag3, tag4 are one grouping and they occur for Question1 and Question2. tag3, tag4, tag5 (Question5) only occur once, no other question has those same three tags. That also goes for tag3 tag5 which only occurs for Question5. Sorry if I'm not clear.

Comment: I don't understand "question has many answers" and "A question only has one answer"?

Comment: Shouldn't it be tag3, tag4 occur 4 times (in questions 1,2,4, and 5)?

Comment: @RyanSparks wow, you're correct. fixed

Comment: @xavier fixed. sorry about that. a question has many answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use a recursive CTE to produce the possible combinations. First select all tag IDs as an array of one element. Then `UNION ALL` a JOIN of the CTE and the tag IDs appending the tag ID to the array if it is larger than the largest ID in the array.

To the CTE join an aggregation getting the tag IDs for every answer as an array. In the `ON` clause check that the answer's array contains the array from the CTE with the array contains operator `@>`.

Exclude the combinations from the CTE with only one tag in a `WHERE` clause as you're not interested in those.

Now `GROUP BY` the combination of tags an exclude all the combinations which occur less than twice in a `HAVING` clause -- you're not interested in them too. If you want you also "translate" the IDs to the names of the tags in the `SELECT` list.

```
WITH RECURSIVE "cte"
AS
(
SELECT ARRAY["t"."id"] "id"
       FROM "tags" "t"
UNION ALL
SELECT "c"."id" || "t"."id" "id"
       FROM "cte" "c"
            INNER JOIN "tags" "t"
                       ON "t"."id" > (SELECT max("un"."e")
                                             FROM unnest("c"."id") "un" ("e"))
)
SELECT "c"."id" "id",
       (SELECT array_agg("t"."text")
               FROM unnest("c"."id") "un" ("e")
                    INNER JOIN "tags" "t"
                               ON "t"."id" = "un"."e") "text",
       count(*) "count"
       FROM "cte" "c"
            INNER JOIN (SELECT array_agg("at"."tag_id" ORDER BY "at"."tag_id") "id"
                               FROM "answer_tags" "at"
                               GROUP BY at.answer_id) "x"
                       ON "x"."id" @> "c"."id"
       WHERE array_length("c"."id", 1) > 1
       GROUP BY "c"."id"
       HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Result:

```
 id      | text             | count
---------+------------------+-------
 {2,3}   | {tag2,tag3}      |     2
 {3,4}   | {tag3,tag4}      |     4
 {2,4}   | {tag2,tag4}      |     2
 {2,3,4} | {tag2,tag3,tag4} |     2
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=0a9bfeac5437e7303026b449f68da029)

Answer (score 4):

Building on @filiprem's answer and using a slightly modified function from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560614/how-to-find-all-combinations-subset-of-any-size-of-an-array-in-postgresql) you get:

```
--test data
create table questions (id int, text varchar(100));
create table answers (id int, text varchar(100), question_id int);
create table answer_tags (id int, answer_id int, tag_id int);
create table tags (id int, text varchar(100));

insert into questions values (1, 'question1'), (2, 'question2'), (3, 'question3'), (4, 'question4'), (5, 'question5');
insert into answers values (1, 'answer1', 1), (2, 'answer2', 2), (3, 'answer3', 3), (4, 'answer4', 4), (5, 'answer5', 5), (6, 'answer6', 1);
insert into tags values (1, 'tag1'), (2, 'tag2'), (3, 'tag3'), (4, 'tag4'), (5, 'tag5');
insert into answer_tags values 
(1,1,1), (2,1,2), (3,1,3), (4,1,4),
(5,2,2), (6,2,3), (7,2,4),
(8,3,3), (9,3,4),
(10,4,4),
(11,5,3), (12,5,4), (13,5,5);
--end test data

--function to get all possible combinations from an array with at least 2 elements
create or replace function get_combinations(source anyarray) returns setof anyarray as $$
 with recursive combinations(combination, indices) as (
   select source[i:i], array[i] from generate_subscripts(source, 1) i
   union all
   select c.combination || source[j], c.indices || j
   from   combinations c, generate_subscripts(source, 1) j
   where  j > all(c.indices) and
          array_length(c.combination, 1) <= 2
 )
 select combination from combinations
 where  array_length(combination, 1) >= 2
$$ language sql;

--expected results
SELECT tags, count(*) FROM (
    SELECT q.id, get_combinations(array_agg(DISTINCT t.text)) AS tags
    FROM questions q
    JOIN answers a ON a.question_id = q.id
    JOIN answer_tags at ON at.answer_id = a.id
    JOIN tags t ON t.id = at.tag_id
    GROUP BY q.id
) t1
GROUP BY tags
HAVING count(*)>1;
```

Note: this gives tag2,tag4 occurs 2 times which was missed in the expected results (from questions 1 and 2)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT tags, count(*) FROM (
    SELECT q.id, array_agg(DISTINCT t.text) AS tags
    FROM questions q
    JOIN answers a ON a.question_id = q.id
    JOIN answer_tags at ON at.answer_id = a.id
    JOIN tags t ON t.id = at.tag_id
    GROUP BY q.id
) t1
GROUP BY tags
HAVING count(*)>1;
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Your answer kind of works. It works when the questions have the exact same tags but if one question has two tags, and a second question has three tags then it doesn't return any results.